# Only Cursor and Notifications Appear for First Few Seconds After Display Turns Back On

Tags: macos, imac, sleep-wake, display

When my 2011 iMac's display shuts off - before the computer goes to sleep, but after a screensaver might display - there is frequently a 5-15second delay with the display coming back.

What I see is the backlight on the display come on, showing a completely black screen with the only exceptions being my cursor and any notifications in the upper-right that have appeared since the display shut off.

I can move the cursor around without trouble. I cannot interact with the notifications.

After a delay the rest of the display returns: the dock, open windows, etc... exactly as I left it.

I have only experienced this issue for the last 2-3 months. Is there a way to stop this delay? What causes this?

**Update**

I see the following in the activity console.

```
10/8/14 1:04:59.000 AM kernel[0]: PM notification cancel (pid 129, screens_connectd)

10/8/14 1:05:09.872 AM WindowServer[152]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [193459014260005]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake

10/8/14 1:05:09.873 AM WindowServer[152]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
```

Comment: you need the Console log from the time stamp to analyze what is preventing the display.

Comment: @Buscar I updated my question with a couple log messages.